# VSCode not recognising python modules

Tags: python

I'm writing a program in VSCode, for the mindstorms ev3dev software.
I need to import pyautogui to simulate Keypresses, but VSCode returns this:

```
Starting: brickrun --directory="/home/robot/vscode-hello-python-master" "/home/robot/vscode-hello-python-master/hello.py"
----------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/robot/vscode-hello-python-master/hello.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pyautogui
ImportError: No module named 'pyautogui'
----------
Exited with error code 1.
```

Now, i've tried using a venv, i've tried multiple solutions online, and multiple different modules like numpy or pynput but none seemed to work. (Mysteriously the library I use to communicate with the brick, ev3dev2, works...). VSCode is able to see the module, and give me suggestions to functions like keyUp or keyDown, but when running it, it doesn't work.

Btw, i run the code by 'debugging', idk what that means, i followed some instructions online. The debugging is needed to run the code on the mindstorms brick, I think.

[VSCode recognising module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgQu8.png)

Comment: If you run the command `pip list` do you see `pyautogui` in the output? Do you have more than one version of Python installed on your system?

Comment: VSCode probably has its own Python installation.  You can change its default Python in the settings.  Google can help with that.

Comment: @JRiggles [Pip showing pyautogui](https://imgur.com/a/F6iwoIj)

Comment: @TimRoberts I don't believe VSCode comes with its own Python out of the box

Comment: It seems while coding you are using correct venv but while running, program is executed by some other env or global python path. I advise you to check and select python interpreter(venv). You can select python interpreter via command line (`ctrl+shift+p`) >python interpreter>select venv. And run the python file rather then debugging at top left side you can see `play` button. **PS: You have Python Extension Installed**

Comment: At the bottom of the VSCode window you should see your Python version. You can click on that to specify the appropriate Python interpreter.

Comment: @GodWin i don't use venv, I am using the pc normal python path [Path](https://imgur.com/a/Sg5fC6o)

Comment: You mentioned that you tried with `venv` and modules are running.

Comment: @GodWin i tried, but then i wanted to check if the venv was the problem, and since i found the same problem on the python path, i remained on that

Comment: @GodWin i need to run it as debuggin, else it won't transmit to the brick [EV3 project mine is based on](https://github.com/ev3dev/vscode-hello-python)

Comment: @GodWin lines "11. Press F5 to download the program and run it.

"12. The Output pane will automatically open and show the status of the program and any error/debug messages.